# WP Перенос на хостинг

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-500

На локалке все работает. На хостинге ошибка:

```
POST http://masterpk.epizy.com/wp-content/plugins/wpt-vBSSO-master/query.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Пытаюсь получить JSON данные со стороннего домена: аяксом стучусь к себе на сервер, и через сервер получаю данные со стороннего JSONa. На локальной машине все данные получаются. В чем может быть ошибка. Хостингу что то не нравиться? Какие файлы закинуть сюда, чтобы Вы помогли решить проблему?

Comment: лог ошибок php покажите

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема в неправильном переносе сайта: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение: чтобы кидать запрос с сервера на сервер использовал вместо file_get_content библиотечку curl, и все заработало как часы. А пользовался этой функцией, потому что JSON получитл надо было, и на локалке она прокатывала. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Можно и так. Только обе функции не приветствуются в WordPress, следует использовать wp_remote_get(). Это тот же curl, но в многочисленными улучшениями для надёжной работы на разных хостингах.

Comment: @KAGG Design Видел эту функцию, но проблема в том, что я пишу виджет, а эта функция должна быть в классе wp, когда я даю с Аякса запрос на индексный файл, то получается инициализирую заново класс виджет а. Поделитесь ссылкой, как организовать это с помощью средств wp?

Comment: Делайте ajax по правилам WP: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html и у вас во время ajax будет подгружена среда WP

Comment: @KAGG Design спасибо!